# Python Azure Function not working with higher Python version installed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I am running Python Azure Functions with Visual Code and Python version 3.12 and I also have Python 3.9 installed on my machine.
When I try to run my Azure Function using the terminal with the command:

```
  func host start
```

I am getting the error -

```
 Found Python version 3.12.0 (py).
 Python 3.6.x to 3.10.x is required for this operation. Please install Python 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, or 3.10 and use a virtual environment to switch to Python 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, or 3.10.
```

I have set the environment path of the latest (3.12) Python as well, but still, it doesn't seem to work.
.venv is also created using Python 3.12

Please anyone suggest a solution.

Comment: Did you try with Python version 3.9?

Comment: I did, didn't work. Same error again and again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Python 3.6.x to 3.10.x is required for this operation. Please install Python 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, or 3.10 and use a virtual environment to switch to Python 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, or 3.10.

I followed below steps to resolve this error:

- I have below versions of Python:

```
C:\Users\username\pylatestfn>py --list
 -V:3.12 *        Python 3.12 (64-bit)
 -V:3.11          Python 3.11 (64-bit)
 -V:3.9           Python 3.9 (64-bit)
 -V:3.9-32        Python 3.9 (32-bit)
```

- Configured Environment variables in my system to use **Python 3.9**.

1. Create a new Python function in VSCode.
2. Select `Python 3.9` as Python Interpreter to create virtual environment.
3. If you can't find required version, skip the virtual environment and configure it after creation of function.

- To configure virtual environment manually, go to command palette (ctrl+shift+p)=> search for `select python Interpreter` and select `Python 3.9`.

[image]

- Run the commands to create and activate virtual environment:

```
py -m venv .venv
.\.venv\Scripts\activate
```

4. Navigate to `.venv=>pyvenv.cfg`, the version should be `3.9`:

**pyvenv.cfg:**

```
home = C:\Users\uname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.9.10
```

**Run the function:**

- ***Virtual Environment should be activated before running the function.*** , otherwise `Python 3.12` version will be used.

[image]

- Activated virtual environment and able to run the function as expected:

[image]